# Cannot SSH or connect to remote user connected within same VPN network

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

There are two users A and B. They both are remotely working from different locations.
And they can SSH to office server located on other side via VPN.
But when User A tries to ssh to User B, they cannot ping or connect to each other even if they are connected to same VPN network.

I am very new to this situation.
Kindly help...

Thanks

Comment: Check with whoever configured the VPN if they have configured it to disallow client to client-communication. That's a quite common configuration option.

Comment: what is the output that appears when user A trying to connect to user B or B to A?

Comment: @johncli Nothing appears. Also the command doesn't executes.

Comment: @vidarlo Ok. Thanks. I'll try this solution.